# Recursive Generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, recursive-type

I want to declare a simple type to replace `any` in a piece of code. I know it will be some object-ish argument, so I could use `Record<string, unknown>`, but I'd rather be a *little* more specific.

This would be ideal:

```
type MyObject = Record<string, string | string[] | number | boolean | MyObject>
```

but it gives the error

> Type alias 'MyObject' circularly references itself.ts(2456)

I can get around this by cheating with interfaces:

```
type MyObject<T> = Record<string, string | string[] | number | boolean | T>

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
interface IMyObject extends MyObject<IMyObject>{}
```

Is there a way to do what I want, or should I just stick to `Record<string, unknown>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler gives up before it can realize that the type you are specifying is recursive in a supported way, because it does not probe the definition of [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) before checking for circularity.  This is a design limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#41164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164) for an explanation.

The fix here is to replace `Record<string, XYZ>` with what it eventually becomes, a type with a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) like `{ [k: string]: XYZ }`:

```
type MyObject = 
  { [k: string]: string | string[] | number | boolean | MyObject } // okay
```

which works without error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsKBeKBvKA2gNYBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYC6ZltjUAPhdfQwUy5Q6AVwC2iCFSGIA9rIA2EAIZ0hcJKgxQAvkA)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make it a generic

```
type MyObject = Record<string, string | string[] | number | boolean | IMyObject>
interface IMyObject extends MyObject {}
```